# Calculate uptime server php

Tags: php, mysql

I have top servers site. I need calculate uptime for every server. 

I have table stats in database, where stats all servers:

Table have columns: 
- server_id - column id from table servers 
- status - server online/offline. 1 = online 0 = offline 
- online - count online players 
- created_at - date when record is created. Format: TIMESTAMP

I have cron, that check all servers from database. Every 10 min cron check: 
- if server online 
- count of players online

And cron write this all in stats table. 
I want calculate uptime server how here: [minecraft server page uptime example](http://minecraftservers.org/server/410060)

I try this code:

```
SELECT ((COUNT(1) / tmp.total) * 100) AS percentage 
FROM stats AS sts 
CROSS JOIN (
     SELECT COUNT(1) AS total 
     FROM stats 
     WHERE DATE(created_at)=CURDATE()
) AS tmp  
WHERE DATE(created_at)=CURDATE()
GROUP BY sts.server_id, tmp.total;
```

But this query with bad perfomance and not correctly. 
I think, that formula for calculation server uptime is:

```
uptime : this.server with online = 1 / this.server with online = 0  * 100
```

I need get percentage (uptime server) how in this example:

[minecraft server page uptime example](http://minecraftservers.org/server/410060)

How I can do this with php and mysql query?

Comment: Try looking at the EXPLAIN for your query to determine if you need to add indexes to improve performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// query all the times a server is offline
$query = "SELECT server_id,COUNT(IF(online=0,1, NULL)),COUNT(*) FROM uptime GROUP BY server_id";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

// iterate through all server_id's
while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
        echo "Server ID: ".$row[0]." -- Uptime: ";
        if($row[1] == 0){
            $uptime = 100;
        }else{
            $uptime = $row[1] / $row[2];
            $uptime = round(100-($uptime*100),2);
        }

        echo $uptime."%<br>";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Server ID: 1 -- Uptime: 93.25%
Server ID: 2 -- Uptime: 93%
Server ID: 3 -- Uptime: 100%
Server ID: 4 -- Uptime: 100%
Server ID: 5 -- Uptime: 94.08%
Server ID: 6 -- Uptime: 92.75%
Server ID: 7 -- Uptime: 93.83%
Server ID: 8 -- Uptime: 94.58%
Server ID: 9 -- Uptime: 95.25%
Server ID: 10 -- Uptime: 94.42%
```

**TEST CODE USED TO VERIFY EXAMPLE ABOVE:**

```
$servers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; // create 10 random servers

for($i = 0; $i < 600; $i++){ // create 10 hours of data
        foreach($servers as $server){
                $players = 0; // no players unless online
                $online = rand(0,100); // create artificial 5% down time
                if($online > 5 || $server == 3 || $server == 4){
                        $players = rand(1,50); // choose random player count
                        $online = 1;
                }else{
                        $online = 0; // server was offline
                }

                // add status
                $query = "INSERT INTO uptime (server_id, status, online) VALUES ($server, $online, $players)";
                // echo $mysqli->error;
                $mysqli->query($query);
        }
}
```

Comment: But if I don't have `online = 0` in database. When will be uptime: 100% ?

Comment: You will never have 100%. You might as well make the very first entry for every server online=0.

Comment: Why? If server always online? Why I need do online = 0? If server online..

Comment: Add an if/else statement after the initial query. If there are no results, then your uptime is 100%.

Comment: Can you please help do this statement?

Comment: Done. All completed in 1 statement now.

Comment: But why you check `$row[1]` if equals 0?

Comment: $row[1] contains the count of "online=0" from the table. If $row[1] == 0 then that means the server has never gone offline, meaning you don't need to do any math. It's just 100.